# Gradle Build Failed after working with test mode on?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, exception, build

everyone.

I was building my android project on Unity 2019.2.5. Now please forgive me- I honestly don't know what information is needed to answer this question. This game built with Test Mode on by accident. No big issue- I just turned it off and attempted to rebuild the game under the same name. However, then I got a Gradle Build Fail error. I already rebuilt over the last update of the game, so this should not be the issue. The only guess that I can make is that I reset things so that all compatible devices could use the app after building with test mode. After that build failed, I reset to default devices and hit the build button again- but even that didn't fix things. What does this error mean?

Thanks in advance.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.5f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
]
stdout[
> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preReleaseBuild
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues
> Task :generateReleaseResources
> Task :mergeReleaseResources FAILED
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <5557b445b4634c46b2ec8376c040bd34>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to delete this... I just figured it out.

I just had to change the version number.